# Cant add image on flutter project on vscode

Tags: flutter

[Part of the main dart folder code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzAB3.png)

[The Pubspec yaml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL3NO.png)

[Debug console keeps throwing this at me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ZFs.png)

[Debug console also shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUMoi.png)

Everything i know just stuck here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Although it is helpful to at least have images of the code, its far better to have the actual code posted to your question so people can copy and paste it to attempt to make changes to fix it.  If you can update your question to have the actual code in question that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Image.Asset() instead of AssetImage(). Also, the asset folder structure is not visible so I can't say anything about it.
In addition, there is a small mistake in that you wrote "assets" in pubspec.yaml and in the code, you wrote "asset/images" - The "s" of assets is missing

Comment: Hi Nishant Thankyou problem resolved its the S that was missing as you first indicated. Thankyou so much i am just learning flutter and also first time user on Stackoverflow. Thanks so much again.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help you and also I would be happy to inform you that I am too learning flutter and using StackOverflow to solve my doubts.